# Can't add button on C# forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I do this and can't see button on my form. It worked earlier

```
var delete = new Button
{
    Text = "Delete",
    Size = new Size(50, 50),
    Location = new Point(50, 50),
};
this.Controls.Add(delete);
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in that code. Try it on a simple winform. You might have some panels or some other controls hiding it.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a dynamic button yourself. Is there any specific need? You can drag and drop a button control from toolbox on the form designer. When you do so then all the relevant code for creating button gets added automatically in `designer.cs` file. You don't have to take that pain of creating a button yourself.

Comment: continuing @RBT comment , if you are doing this because you only want to see the button sometimes it is easier to hide it (Visible = false)

Comment: When you say “It worked earlier” do you mean you tried this code twice in a row? You're drawing the two buttons at the same size at the same location, the second one will conceal the first.